# Нужно разобрать массив с зависимостями от родительских элементов

Tags: javascript

Есть объект данных и нужно разобрать его записывая каждый ид и его родителя.

Мой вариант:

```js
const object = {"id":"1","sub_id":[{"id":"1.1","sub_id":[{"id":"1.1.1"},{"id":"1.1.2"},{"id":"1.1.3"}]},{"id":"1.2","sub_id":[{"id":"1.2.1"},{"id":"1.2.2"},{"id":"1.2.3"},{"id":"1.2.4","sub_id":[{"id":"1.2.4.1"}]}]}]};

let data = object;
let relation = undefined;

function objectParsing(data) {
    if (data["sub_id"] != undefined) {

        for (let key in data) {
            if (key == 'id') {
                console.log('Create new id: ' + data[key]);
                if (relation != undefined) {
                    console.log('Create parent: ' + relation + '_id for id: ' + data[key]);
                    relation = data[key];
                    console.log('Store new relation: ', relation);
                } else {
                    relation = data[key];
                }
            }
            if (key == 'sub_id') {
                data[key].forEach(function (item, i, arr) {
                    objectParsing(item);
                });
            }
        }

    } else {
        for (let key in data) {
            console.log('Create new id: ' + data[key]);
            if (relation != undefined) {
                console.log('Create relation: ' + relation + '_id for id: ' + data[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}

objectParsing(data);
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Create new id: 1
Create new id: 1.1
Create parent: 1_id for id: 1.1
Store new relation:  1.1
Create new id: 1.1.1
Create relation: 1.1_id for id: 1.1.1
Create new id: 1.1.2
Create relation: 1.1_id for id: 1.1.2
Create new id: 1.1.3
Create relation: 1.1_id for id: 1.1.3
Create new id: 1.2
Create parent: 1.1_id for id: 1.2 // проблема тут
Store new relation:  1.2
Create new id: 1.2.1
Create relation: 1.2_id for id: 1.2.1
Create new id: 1.2.2
Create relation: 1.2_id for id: 1.2.2
Create new id: 1.2.3
Create relation: 1.2_id for id: 1.2.3
Create new id: 1.2.4
Create parent: 1.2_id for id: 1.2.4
Store new relation:  1.2.4
Create new id: 1.2.4.1
Create relation: 1.2.4_id for id: 1.2.4.1
```

Для `id 1.2` я затираю зависимость от `id 1` - помогите поправить с учетом, что глубина объекта может быть условно не ограниченной, заодно может и более оптимальный путь есть.

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Получить в итоге массив с данными а-ля `{ id, parent_id }`?

Comment: Почти. Так то они будут записываться в базу, а это версия алгоритма без излишеств.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По факту вам требуется брать `id` элемента и запускать рекурсию по всем `sub_id` этого объекта.

Это версия с выводом в консоль:

```js
const object = {"id":"1","sub_id":[{"id":"1.1","sub_id":[{"id":"1.1.1"},{"id":"1.1.2"},{"id":"1.1.3"}]},{"id":"1.2","sub_id":[{"id":"1.2.1"},{"id":"1.2.2"},{"id":"1.2.3"},{"id":"1.2.4","sub_id":[{"id":"1.2.4.1"}]}]}]};

function writeLine(text) {
  // console.log(text);
  document.write(text + "<br>");
}

function objectParsing(data, parentId) {
  writeLine("Create new id: " + data.id);
  if (data.sub_id) {
    data.sub_id.forEach(item => {
      objectParsing(item, data.id);
      writeLine("Create parent: " + data.id + "_id for: " + item.id);
    });
    if (parentId) {
      writeLine("Store new relation: " + data.id);
    }
  }
}

objectParsing(object);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

Это версия с созданием одномерного массива:

```js
const object = {"id":"1","sub_id":[{"id":"1.1","sub_id":[{"id":"1.1.1"},{"id":"1.1.2"},{"id":"1.1.3"}]},{"id":"1.2","sub_id":[{"id":"1.2.1"},{"id":"1.2.2"},{"id":"1.2.3"},{"id":"1.2.4","sub_id":[{"id":"1.2.4.1"}]}]}]}

var results = [];

function objectParsing(data, parentId = null) {
  results.push({
    id: data.id,
    parent_id: parentId
  });
  if (data.sub_id) {
    data.sub_id.forEach(item => {
      objectParsing(item, data.id);
    });
  }
}

objectParsing(object);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблема в том, что мне нужно сначала создавать id в базе данных иначе я не буду знать его id, а потом к нему зависимость.

Comment: @SergeiR обновил ответ. Так устроит?

Comment: Вывод должен быть Create new id: 1; Create new id: 1.1; Create parent: 1_id for: 1.1; Если к примеру заменить id на Вася и Петя то логика такова, что Сначала создаем Васю получаем его id от db, запоминаем что Вася есть папа, потом создаем Петю, получаем его id от db и тогда создаем связь в таблицу relations где есть поля id (autoincrement), parents_id, self_id.

Comment: @SergeiR интересная у вас задача. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @SergeiR кстати, что за бд у вас, если не секрет? :)

Comment: Не секрет postgresql и sequelize к ней